# how to handle php redirects for different environments

Tags: php, redirect

I'm developing a php application that involves creating a session and redirecting a user to a dashboard page after the session is successfully created. I currently use the following code:

```
if ($success) {
    header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/dashboard.php");
}
```

I'm working on making my application available for others to download and use on their own servers, so I'm looking for another way to write the redirect code above so that it's not restricted to only `mydomain.com`. How do you handle php redirects for any domain? Can `header()` work with relative paths such as `header("Location: ./dashboard.php");` ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but what exactly the problem? I think that you shouldn't use the dot at the begining.
header("location: /dashboard.php")

In general, you can use $_SERVER global var for this purposes. In $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] you have the name of the virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I have used the `$_SERVER` global to get the domain of the current website.

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

One downside to this approach is that the application may not be running in the top directory. So, normally what I have done is in the index.php (all requests are routed through index.php) I defined a constant with the base path and the domain, so something like this:

```
define('BASE_PATH', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])['dirname']);
```

Comment: Use `HTTP_HOST` if set if going this route: multiple hostnames may end up on the same `SERVER_NAME` in some setups.

Comment: *sigh* ... **BE VERY CAREFUL WITH BOTH `HTTP_HOST` AND `SERVER_NAME`** as both are hacker controlled. It's possible with certain virtual host setups to place your own value in `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and the `Host` header is always user controlled. You should never blindly trust these values. At least check the host against a case-normalized whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for do this is to keep a `configuration.php` file where you can store all this information (customized on final user needs) and retrieve all you need from this file.

This file could be "composed" with an init script or something like this (if you have a backoffice, even directly stored in DB or make writeable this file by your backoffice itself, *with all risks of the case*)

Comment: so, for instance, in the config.php file, have a `$yourDomain = /* Please add your domain */` and use that variable in the `header()` function?

Comment: @br14np: yes, more or less. This is useful in various scenery. I.E.: you could save only domain name and use it to compose redirects or path, starting from this value and adding slices of strings

Comment: Never thought about using the config file. Good suggestion thanks